# Visual Studio C++ LNK2019 Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm new to C++ programming, I've used DEV CPP as a compiler but then decided to switch to VS C++ to be up to date, and also to become a better coder.

However, compared to DEV CPP, I find Visual Studio to be struggling. I came across this error, which I couldn't solve.

So please help me compile and run my code as a Win32

Here's the problem:

[image]

Comment: You selected the wrong project type. You created a windows project when you wanted a win32 console application. Next time please post the text of the error message from the Output tab instead of a picture.

Comment: Yes, wrong project type....also you can use Code::Blocks instead as a C++ IDE instead of Visual Studio..